# How to select the next or before value from the dropdown after the selected one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a drop down which contains the Time with 30 min slide for each hour and I want to select the next option fallowing selected one. ex: the currently selected time is 7:30 PM so when I run my scenario if my current time is equal to the currently selected time then I should change the time to next slot i.e 8:00 PM. so how to write an xpth or jquery to select the nnext option?

Here is the html:

```
<select id="f-cut-off-time" name="f-cut-off-time" aria-invalid="false" class="valid">
    <option value="6:00AM">6:00AM</option>
    <option value="6:30AM">6:30AM</option>
    <option selected="" disabled="" hidden="" value="7:30PM">7:30PM</option>
    <option value="7:30AM">7:30AM</option>
    <option value="8:00AM">8:00AM</option>
    <option value="8:30AM">8:30AM</option>
    <option value="9:00AM">9:00AM</option>
    <option value="9:30AM">9:30AM</option>
    <option value="10:00AM">10:00AM</option>
    <option value="10:30AM">10:30AM</option>
    <option value="11:00AM">11:00AM</option>
    <option value="11:30AM">11:30AM</option>
    <option value="12:00PM">12:00PM</option>
    <option value="12:30PM">12:30PM</option>
    <option value="1:00PM">1:00PM</option>
    <option value="1:30PM">1:30PM</option>
    <option value="2:00PM">2:00PM</option>
    <option value="2:30PM">2:30PM</option>
    <option value="3:00PM">3:00PM</option>
    <option value="3:30PM">3:30PM</option>
    <option value="4:00PM">4:00PM</option>
    <option value="4:30PM">4:30PM</option>
    <option value="5:00PM">5:00PM</option>
    <option value="5:30PM">5:30PM</option>
    <option value="6:00PM">6:00PM</option>
    <option value="6:30PM">6:30PM</option>
    <option value="7:00PM">7:00PM</option>
    <option value="7:30PM">7:30PM</option>
    <option value="8:00PM">8:00PM</option>
    <option value="8:30PM">8:30PM</option>
    <option value="9:00PM">9:00PM</option>
    <option value="9:30PM">9:30PM</option>
    <option value="10:00PM">10:00PM</option>
    <option value="10:30PM">10:30PM</option>
    <option value="11:00PM">11:00PM</option>
    <option value="11:30PM">11:30PM</option>
    <option value="12:00AM">12:00AM</option>
    <option value="12:30AM">12:30AM</option>
    <option value="1:00AM">1:00AM</option>
    <option value="1:30AM">1:30AM</option>
    <option value="2:00AM">2:00AM</option>
    <option value="2:30AM">2:30AM</option>
    <option value="3:00AM">3:00AM</option>
    <option value="3:30AM">3:30AM</option>
    <option value="4:00AM">4:00AM</option>
    <option value="4:30AM">4:30AM</option>
    <option value="5:00AM">5:00AM</option>
    <option value="5:30AM">5:30AM</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Any reason you're using a select and not a [time input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time) for this? Also do you mean it the current time is equal to or greater than the selected time? Why even show the other times if you don't want users to select it?

Comment: You need to provide us the relevant HTML when _currently selected time is 7:30 PM_

Comment: here is my html code 
 <select id="f-cut-off-time" name="f-cut-off-time" aria-invalid="false" class="valid">
<option selected="" disabled="" hidden="" value="7:30PM">7:30PM</option>
           <option value="6:00AM">6:00AM</option>

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do here, but you can get the option next to the selected one by using `$('option:selected').next()`;

Comment: I need to update one of the field value based on the time, so I am getting the current time using the dateformat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST")); and if the current CST time is equal to selected drop-down time, I should change the dropdown time to next option

Comment: You can use XPath `//option[@selected]/following-sibling::option` to get *immediate next sibling of selected option*

Comment: @Smartcoder I have indented the tags which were out of indent. let me know if the HTML looks perfect now or else I will revert back the change.

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the value like this.

```
<option value="6:00PM">5:30PM</option>
```

That way it will appear as if they are selecting 5:30, but it is outputting 6:00

Comment: Obviously close the tag, but it did wierd stuff on my phone when I closed it and tried to output HTML rather than a code snippet.

Comment: I've edited this to fix it for you several times and you keep changing it again to break it. Please leave it alone when someone has edited your syntax mistakes.,

Comment: Also, this suggestion seems very counter-intuitive and likely to cause more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the selected index of the select element, make sure there is another option that comes after it, and then locate it by index in the options collection of that select element.

```js
$('#timeslot').on('input', function () {
  var i = this.selectedIndex;
  if (i + 1 < this.options.length) {
    console.log("next option value is " + this.options[i + 1].value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='timeslot'>
  <option value="6:00AM">6:00AM</option>
  <option value="6:30AM">6:30AM</option>
  <option value="7:00AM">7:00AM</option>
  <option value="7:30AM">7:30AM</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To select the *next* or *previous* option from the dropdown after or before the `selected` option you can use the following solution:

- *Next* option:

  - *XPath*:

    ```
    //select[@class='valid' and @id='f-cut-off-time']//option[@selected]//following::option[1]
    ```
  - Browser snapshot:

[image: next]

- *Previous* option:

  - *XPath*:

    ```
    //select[@class='valid' and @id='f-cut-off-time']//option[@selected]//preceding::option[1]
    ```
  - Browser snapshot:

[image: previous]

Comment: <select id="f-cut-off-time" name="f-cut-off-time" aria-invalid="false" class="valid">                                                                                                             
<option selected="" disabled="" hidden="" value="7:00AM">7:00AM</option>                                             above one is the html and based on your input I have written the code as below, but not working                                                                                                   
 //select[@id='f-cut-off-time']//option[@selected]//following::option[1]

Comment: <option value="6:00AM">6:00AM</option>
           <option value="6:30AM">6:30AM</option>
           <option value="7:00AM">7:00AM</option>
           <option value="7:30AM">7:30AM</option>
           <option value="8:00AM">8:00AM</option>                                                   based on the above xptah its identifiyng the 6:00AM But i want to select the 7:30AM as it's next to the selected time value, please help me to get this one

Comment: @Smartcoder Checkout my updated answer and let me know the result. Perhaps when **7:00AM** is `selected` I am getting proper results as **7:30AM** and **6:30AM**.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you , you need to use :

```
$('option:selected').next() or 
$('option:selected').prev()
```